# No "chat" option in Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 for facebook account

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, facebook, online-accounts

How can I make Online Accounts display the "Chat" option for Facebook so I could enable it for Empathy again?

After upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04 there's only "Photos" option for Facebook in Settings -> Online Accounts so I can't enable "Chat". Facebook XMPP resource also disappeared from Empathy's configuration. Google account prevailed the upgrade without issue and is present in both above mentioned places.

Comment: This does not answer your questions, but be aware that the reason this was removed is probably because using Empathy or Pidgin (or any XMPP client) for Facebook will stop / may already have stopped working. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still open **Empathy**, go to the "Accounts" section and add a "Facebook chat" account type. That worked for me.

Comment: It isn't the same thing but I guess it'll do.